# Matlab Matrix within an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I am trying to load data files into my workspace. I need to do some preprosessing on them so I want to put them in an array. These data files are matrices of 4 columns with roughly 1500 rows. I was looking at the matrix in matrix but I can't properly visualise it and implement it. When I call one of the indexes of the array it should return me the matrix of the datafile. How would I go about this?
In a sense I want to create an array of the objects of the data files to put it in for me more familiar terms.
Thank you

Comment: You may want to look a cell arrays.

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for and it worked immediately Thank you!